# Kotlin HashSet wrong behaviour (bug)

Tags: android, kotlin, set, hashset

I've got a strange behaviour of the `HashSet` class. I don't know why, but method `contains` returns wrong result. Here an image from debugger:

[image: Debugger]
`rootElemetns` is a `HashSet` that contains some `FsEntries` that are represented by a simple data class (without any aditional methods, only fields). As You can see `fsEntry` that passed to the method  `contains` is the same element as the highlited element (address @8939 is the same).

Why `contains` returns `false`, but `indexOf` is 5? Is this unknown Kotlin bug? Thanks in advance.

Version of Kotlin plugin: 1.3.40

P.S With other elements in this `Set` I've got the correct result.

P.P.S. As You can see if I convert `rootElements` via `toArray()` method it also returns correct result

Comment: Are you altering the object after inserting it into the Set? You're  probably messing with the hash that it has stored.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Hm, may be there one field changed. I'll check it tomorrow. Thanks for idea.

Comment: If that's the case, then you're likely violating requirements of the Set. In Java, you can't alter the keys of a HashMap (which HashSets are backed by). It's likely similar in Kotlin. When you insert the object, it hashes it and puts it in a slot depending on the hash. If you then alter the object, the hash will change, and when it hashes the object during the membership test, the hashes will be different, and the lookup with fail.

Comment: If you need the inserted objects to be mutable, consider using a HashMap instead, associating the object with some ID key, and doing lookups on the ID instead. It's OK if the values changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Carcigenicate and I post the given answer as correct.

"If that's the case, then you're likely violating requirements of the Set. In Java, you can't alter the keys of a HashMap (which HashSets are backed by). It's likely similar in Kotlin. When you insert the object, it hashes it and puts it in a slot depending on the hash. If you then alter the object, the hash will change, and when it hashes the object during the membership test, the hashes will be different, and the lookup with fail."